# CollectionView cuts off cells during animation

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a collectionView that is anchored to another subview inside my viewController. The orange subview is anchored to the bottom of the navigation bar, and its height and alpha values get animated.

When its animated, the collecitonView is shifted down along during the animation. Although, as you'll see, some of the lower cells disappear before the animation making it look unsmooth and jagged.

[image]

This is the function that sets up the subviews of the viewController:

```
private func setupSubviews() {
    view.addSubview(newMessageView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        newMessageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        newMessageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        newMessageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    newMessageView.heightConstraint = newMessageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    newMessageView.heightConstraint?.isActive = true


    view.addSubview(messagesCollectionView)
    messagesCollectionView.anchor(top: newMessageView.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
}
```

This is the function that is being called:

```
@objc func newMessage() {

toggleHeader = !toggleHeader

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

    if (self.toggleHeader) {
        self.newMessageView.heightConstraint?.constant = 200
    } else {
        self.newMessageView.heightConstraint?.constant = 0
    }

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

}

I'm simply changing the heightConstraint that I've imposed. I believe it has to do with the didEndDisplaying function, that detects that the cells won't be visible and cuts them off.

How would I change or improve this? Or is there a way to stop the collectionView from removing the non displayed cells?

Thanks

Comment: Share you code please

Comment: Ok. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Fixed it.

Changed the bottom anchor of the collectionView to view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.

Comment: I was about to say that (: Actually thought you should add setLayoutIfNeeded on messagesCollectionView too, but if it works like this then perfect